# Unable to add backround image to header behind navmenu

Tags: html, css, menu, header

So basically, I was trying to add an image behind my nav menu. It ended up with me not even being able to add an image to the header anymore? No matter how I try it does not show up. Even before this, when it did show up, the header image appeared above the menu, as to what I'm looking for whereas the menu is "on-top" of the image.

**CSS**

```
#dolphincontainer{position:relative; color:#E0E0E0;
padding-top:40px;
width:100%;font-family:Helvetica,Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;}
#dolphinnav{position:relative;;font-size:16px;text-transform:uppercase;font-    weight:bold;padding:0 0 0 60px;}
#dolphinnav ul{margin:0;padding:0;list-style-type:none;width:auto;float:left;}
#dolphinnav ul li{display:block;float:left;margin:0 1px;margin-top:-22px;}
#dolphinnav ul li a{display:block;float:left;color:#3D3D3D;text-decoration:none;padding:8px;height:30px;width:60px;}
#dolphinnav ul li a span{padding:12px 20px 0 0;height:21px;float:left;}
#dolphinnav ul li a:hover{background-color:#3D3D3D ;}
#dolphinnav ul li a:hover span{display:block;color:white;width:auto;cursor:pointer;}


#dolphinnav ul li a.current span{display:block;width:auto; no-repeat top right;height:33px;}

#dolphin_inner{color: white; padding: 5px; font-size: 80%; height: 1em}

#dolphin_inner a:link, #dolphin_inner a:visited, #dolphin_inner a:active{color:#fff}
#dolphin_inner a:hover{color: white}

body {background-color:#000000;}
#header {
background:url(images/header.png);
}




.innercontent{display: none;}

#footer_menu ul{
list-style: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 10px 0 0 10px;
position:absolute;bottom:50px;    
font-family:Helvetica,Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;
font-weight:bold;
font-size:12px;
}
#footer_menu ul li{
padding:0;
margin: 0 0 0 30px;
display:inline;


}
#footer_menu ul li a:link,a:visited,a:focus,a:active{
text-decoration:  none;
color: #3D3D3D;


}
#footer_menu ul li a:hover{
text-decoration:  none;
color: #fff; 
}
```

**HTML**

```
<body>

<div id"header">

<div id="dolphincontainer">
<div id="dolphinnav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html"><span>Home</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html"><span>About</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="dolphin_inner">
    <div id="about" class="innercontent"></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
//dolphintabs.init("ID_OF_TAB_MENU_ITSELF", SELECTED_INDEX)
dolphintabs.init("dolphinnav", 0)
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

A little CSS should do the trick:

```
 #dolphinnav{ background-image: url('image-url-relative-to-css.png');
              background-repeat: repeat-x; }
```

Or no-repeat....

Comment: Still nothing.. I know there's something I'm not seeing, but like, I've been going at this for like an hour haha. When checking with firebug, it says filepath not found, as it's been doing for hours..

Comment: Anyways, now, it finds the filepath and displays the picture within FireBug, but nothing in the website.

Comment: Another update. By adding 'display:table;' after 'no-repeat-x;' the image shows up, I also added 'width:100%', which makes it stretch over the whole screen horizontally. But it's tiny vertically, it only covers the letters of my menu, when it's supposed to cover maybe 4 times as much space.